# Unable to add new user using Directory Service after 2013 upgrade

Tags: 2013, 2013-sp1

After 2013 SP1 upgrade we are unable to **add new user** using **Directory Service**. We are getting below error

> Unable to list users from
>   Error occurred while searching in LDAP subtree 'OU=XXXXX,DC=XXXXX,DC=XXXXX,DC=XX' with filter '(sAMAccountName=*)'.
>   The size limit was exceeded

Before upgrade(in 2011 SP1) this was working fine.

Adding new user using **domain** is working fine in 2013 SP1.

Please share if you have any any work around on this.

Comment: To be clear the problem is not with adding user, the problem is with listing the directory. You are still able to add user through API

Comment: @ user978511 - Agree. I'm able to add new user by selecting domain but when I select the Directory Service, its throwing above exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a defect with 2013 in that it always submits a wildcard ("*") search to LDAP without taking in the inputted username in the search user field. We know this from the logs.

The workaround is provided by an extension available from Customer Support as per Bogdan's answer here: https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/8278/159